# How would I change the state of a switch button based on a cell value in a google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am creating a time in and time out web app using google app script. I have a switch button that toggles between Time In and Time out. However I want to create a column in the User sheet to store if the user is currently timed in or timed out for each and changed when they select the button. Based on that value the toggle button would show if to time in or time out and then carry out the function. I'm honestly not 100% sure how to even start this aspect.

In a separate file I just made the time in and time out button and their functionality. Below is the code for the time in and time out in the html file with the user "login".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="login(event)">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" required><br>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" required><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

<button id="ContButton" onclick="openForm()" hidden>Dashboard</button>

<div class="form-popup" id="Dashboard">

  <form class="form-container">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <p>Welcome, <span id="name"></span></p>
    <p>Number: <span id="number"></span></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id ="timebutton" onclick="switchbutton()">Time In</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>

  </form>
</div>
    <script>
      //Login function event handler
      function login(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            alert("Logged in");
            let p = document.getElementById('ContButton'); //unhidding the dashboard button when the user logs in successfully 
            p.removeAttribute("hidden");
            localStorage.userSession = JSON.stringify(user);
            //for dashboard pulling from local storage.
            var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.userSession);
            console.log(user);
            document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = user[2];
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = user[3];
          } else {
            alert('Incorrect username or password');
          }
        }).checkLogin(username, password);
      }

      

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("Dashboard").style.display = "block";
}


// function also clears fields for the next user when they close the dashboard.
function closeForm() {
  localStorage.clear();
    window.location.replace = "/";

}

//function to switch the text on the Time in/Time out button and trigger the function for each
function switchbutton(){
   var x = document.getElementById("timebutton");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Time In") {
    x.innerHTML = "Time Out";
    flipIn();
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Time In";
    flipOut();
  }
}

// function to Time In with alert
function flipIn(){
alert("Timed In");
return;
}
//function to Time Out with alert
function flipOut(){
alert("Timed Out");
return;
}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the code.gs file

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yK6WEr3Pp0uzRLlO3mR1E6aKBgyBNoEEbqu6M944O-A').getSheetByName('User');


function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

function checkLogin(username,password) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === username && data[i][1] === password) {
      return data[i];
    }
  }
}

function getUserData(username) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === username) {
      return {
        username: data[i][0],
        name: data[i][2],
        number: data[i][3]
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just start and let your failures guide you to success and don't give up.  I would consider using `google.script.run`.  Make simple progress at first by just getting the switch by itself to work the way you wish.

Comment: Hi @Cooper I hot the switch to work (like the toggling of the buttons itself) now its just how to append an existing cell in the google sheet and have the button status change based on the value in that cell for that user.

Comment: appending is just getting what you already have and  adding the new to it and saving it again.  You can poll for that value using setInterval client side  and google.script.run

Answer (score 0):

Toggling A Button:

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Time In" onClick="toggleSwitch(this);">
  <script>
    function toggleSwitch(obj) {
      obj.value = (obj.value == "Time In") ? "Time Out": "Time In"
    }
  console.log("code");  
  </script>  
</body>
</html>
```